# Could not resolve com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1 for zoom-sdk-android-5.5.1.1319

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

Adding the zoom-sdk-android-5.5.1.1319 and commonlib and mobilertc aswell when i am trying to run the app it is showing the error “Could not resolve com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1” Even added the **implementation ‘com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1**’ but could not solve the issue.

```
ext.kotlin_version = “1.5.10”
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2’
classpath “org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version”
}
```

added the error message SS. Can anyone please help me solve this issue

[image]

Comment: You could perhaps wait until the staff answers [here](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/could-not-resolve-com-google-android2-0-1-for-zoom-sdk-android-5-5-1-1319/53921)... (It seems like it's you who asked it based on the username.)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have made mavenCentral as your repository source and com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1 cannot be found in mavenCentral.

Or refer [here](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/could-not-resolve-com-google-android2-0-1-for-zoom-sdk-android-5-5-1-1319/53921/6).